# Use a python class to replace values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary and I would like to replace all the values of a particular key. Here is the input dictionary:

```
{'handlers':
    {'console':
        {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'},
    'info_file_handler':
    {'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': 'INFO', 'formatter': 'simple',
            'filename': 'var/info.log',
            'maxBytes': 10485760,
            'backupCount': 20,
            'encoding': 'utf8'},
    'error_file_handler':
    {'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'filename': 'var/errors.log',
            'maxBytes': 10485760,
            'backupCount': 20,
            'encoding': 'utf8'}
    }
}
```

My objective is to replace the value of certain keys anywhere in the nested dictionary thru a class and not a function. I already have a function working for this but want to transform it as a class. The class will help me to treat the dictionary as an object appending/ inserting text within the value of certain keys or simply delete a key.
I am not able to figure out why it is not working despite the numbers of hours spent on debugging ...

Below is my code:

```
class ObjDict():
    def __init__(self, dictionary=None):
        if dictionary is not None:
            self.__dict__.update(dictionary)

    def replace_value(self, key_searched, new_value):
        print('---------------------------------------')
        for k, value in self.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self.__dict__[k] = ObjDict.replace_value(value, key_searched, new_value)
        if key_searched in self.__dict__:
            # replace the value
            self.__dict__[key_searched] = new_value
            print('Value replaced:', self.__dict__[key_searched])
        return self.__dict__

instance = ObjDict({'handlers': {'console': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler', 'level': 'DEBUG', 'formatter': 'simple', 'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'}, 'info_file_handler': {'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler', 'level': 'INFO', 'formatter': 'simple', 'filename': 'var/info.log', 'maxBytes': 10485760, 'backupCount': 20, 'encoding': 'utf8'}, 'error_file_handler': {'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler', 'level': 'ERROR', 'formatter': 'simple', 'filename': 'var/errors.log', 'maxBytes': 10485760, 'backupCount': 20, 'encoding': 'utf8'}}})
instance.replace_value('filename', "new filename" + "\\")
```

If the key is not nested, works perfectly well. If the key is nested I have following message:

```
for k, value in self.__dict__.items():   AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

The recursion clearly doesn't work the way it should and I am missing something which is beyond my understanding. I have read lots of articles or similar example but sounds not resolving my problem. Solution with explanation will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making the recursive call, you should instantiate a new `ObjDict` instance with `value` so that you can actually call the `replace_value` method on it.

Change:

```
self.__dict__[k] = ObjDict.replace_value(value, key_searched, new_value)
```

to:

```
self.__dict__[k] = ObjDict(value).replace_value(key_searched, new_value)
```

so that:

```
print(instance.replace_value('filename', "new filename" + "\\"))
```

will correctly output:

```
{'handlers': {'error_file_handler': {'formatter': 'simple', 'backupCount': 20, 'level': 'ERROR', 'encoding': 'utf8', 'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler', 'maxBytes': 10485760, 'filename': 'new filename\\'}, 'console': {'formatter': 'simple', 'class': 'logging.StreamHandler', 'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout', 'level': 'DEBUG'}, 'info_file_handler': {'formatter': 'simple', 'backupCount': 20, 'level': 'INFO', 'encoding': 'utf8', 'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler', 'maxBytes': 10485760, 'filename': 'new filename\\'}}}
```

But furthermore, for your purpose you should not update `__dict__` at all since you are not trying to use the keys in the given dict as the object's attributes, and it only introduces the risk of inadvertently overwriting other important attributes of the same names.

The class would be better implemented as a subclass of dict instead:

```
class ObjDict(dict):
    def replace_value(self, key_searched, new_value):
        for k, value in self.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self[k] = ObjDict(value).replace_value(key_searched, new_value)
        if key_searched in self:
            self[key_searched] = new_value
        return self
```

Comment: Fantastic, I understood my error. I should have posted 2 weeks ago! Thanks a lot @blhsing